# Difference between Association and AssociationSet elements in SSDL

Tags: entity-framework

`<Association>` and `<AssociationSet>` are two different elements in `SSDL` part of the `.edmx` file (xml form). Can anyone please explain the difference. Thanks

Comment: You should really move away from .edmx and use Code-First mapping.

Comment: @David Browne,  `Code-First` mapping is a method to create .edmx (EDM=Entity Data Model) just as `Generate from a database` is. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In code-first the mapping metadata is derived from your code and configuration.  In EF6 it still creates the O-Space, C-Space, S-Space with mappings at runtime, but it never creates an .edmx file in your project.  In EF Core there is never .edmx mapping data at all.  So it's really a dead-end technology.